# Alamofire Custom Parameter Encoding

Tags: swift, encoding, alamofire, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm using Alamofire and want to encode my parameters with content type "text/html; charset=utf-8". I followed the documentation https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire for custom parameter encoding and created

```
let custom: (URLRequestConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) -> (NSURLRequest, NSError?) = {
    (URLRequest, parameters) in
    let mutableURLRequest = URLRequest.URLRequest.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
    mutableURLRequest.setValue("text/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    mutableURLRequest.body =  // don't know if I need to set this
    return (mutableURLRequest, nil)
}

func postData(){
    Alamofire.request(.POST, baseUrl, parameters: parameters, encoding: .Custom(custom))
        .responseString{ (request, response, data, error) in
    println("blah")
    }
}
```

I have a problem when I try to use custom in my Alamofire request and get the error "Cannot make responseString with argument list of type ( _, _, _, _)-> _ )" However, this isn't a problem if the encoding is changed to a preset like .URL so the issue seems to be in my implementation of custom?

If it makes a difference my parameters are set here:

```
var parameters = [String: AnyObject]()
func setParams(){
        parameters = [
        "CONTRACT ID" : chosenContract!.iD.toInt()!,
        "FEE AMOUNT" : 0,
        "TRANSACT DATE" : today
    ]
}
```

Comment: Which version of Alamofire are you using?, your code compile fine for me

Comment: I'm using Alamofire version 1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple questions in here. Let's break them down 1x1.

### Compiler Issue

Your compiler issue is due to the fact that your return tuple is the wrong type. In Alamofire 1.3.0, we changed the return type to be an `NSMutableURLRequest` which ends up making things much easier overall. That should fix your compiler issue.

### Setting the HTTPBody

Now you have a couple options here.

#### Option 1 - Encode Data as JSON

```
let options = NSJSONWritingOptions()
let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters!, options: options)

mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = data
```

> From what you posted I'm assuming you actually want .URL encoding for the parameters.

#### Option 2 - Use the .URL Case

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [:] // fill in
let encodableURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL)
let encodedURLRequest = ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(encodableURLRequest, parameters).0

let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: encodedURLRequest.URLString)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
mutableURLRequest.setValue("text/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
         .response { request, response, data, error in
             print(request)
             print(response)
             print(error)
         }
```

Hopefully that helps get you going. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the through response! I fixed the NSMutableURLRequest and the compiler error went away. Also, my issue with the encoding was just a misunderstanding in how requests work, I really only needed .URL

Comment: Awesome! If you feel it was a sufficient answer, then you should upvote and mark as the correct answer.

Comment: So I have a similar issue which I cannot figure out. I am sending a GET request, but my parameters are not getting formatted correctly. Here's what it should look like `http://dev.plango.us/layout.html#/find-a-plan?selectedPlaces=city:New%20York,state:NY,country:United%20States` but instead I get `http://dev.plango.us/findplans?selectedPlaces=city%3ANew%20York%2Cstate%3ANew%20York%2Ccountry%3AUnited%20States` How do I make it format the colons and commas correctly?